# Unset Form Submit after shell_exec output

Tags: php, isset, shell-exec

I know there are many Questions with the same title but I'm really confused about this problem. I want to execute a shell command when I push a button + I want to see the result. And when I send the form again, I want to reload the output. For example:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $output = shell_exec('dir');
        echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
    }
?>
<form method="post">
    <button name="submit">Start</button>
</form>
```

But when I load this example, the shell command output is already shown. It doesn't wait for the push. How can I solve the Problem?

> EDIT: There are difference between refreshing a side an retyping the address. After retyping, the side is waiting for the push command.

Comment: How are you loading the example? Are you loading it from a previous page via POST?

Comment: I run this example on xampp-Server and only this few lines -no previous page.

Comment: Do you have safemode turned off?

Comment: Yes, the shell_exec command is working

Comment: are you pressing refresh or retyping the address, as once you submitted and tried refreshing afterwards, it will keep posting your form.

Comment: Ah ok, there are difference between refreshing the side an retyping the address. I didn't know this.